# Charging a metal by friction

Tags: electrostatics, conductors

Why is it so difficult to charge a metal by friction, even if the metal is insulated? (For example, rubbing a fork hold by my hand wearing a plastic glove?)

If I wear a glove, electrons can't pass through my body, so they should remain on the fork; but I've tried this little experiment and it didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! We appreciate your question. What is your understanding of solid state physics and electrons in the two components metal and plastic? I recommend to put your thoughts on that as a second paragraph to the question. Please add your level of background knowledge, as well. This is discribed in our help page as "What have you tried to solve the problem".

Comment: I've studied physics, but this problem has not an answer in textbooks

Comment: The correct way of the answer is to compare the two type of materials. The free moving electrons in a metal are different from the ones in plastic. HInt: google Drude model and dipoles in plastics like PET. Please describe your thought process in the question. It is no shame, if you stop at a point of research. Than we can help from that as a starting point. Even better, if you find the answer yourself: You may answer your own question. Since this is not a chat, I stop answering here. I'll be availabe in chat for follow up.

Comment: Ok, but from your comment you seem to think that it is enough to google to find a simple answer; if it were so, I would have not made a post on physics.stackexchange

Comment: @StefanBischof "The free moving electrons in a metal are different from the ones in plastic." You can be understood so that the electrons in metal and in plastic are different particles:)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that insulators may be (and mostly are) charged *only on their surfaces*, so they need only a *small fraction of effort* to charge them in comparison to conductors.

(Conductors conducts charge to their whole volumes, so it's impossible to charge only part of them.)

Moreover, insulator is mostly charged only *on a part of its surface* — that part which is affected by friction.

Comment: Are you saying that if I charge by friction a metal this charge spreads over all its surface and so the effect is weaker than in the case of an insulator?

Comment: Yes — much much much weaker. You may imagine the difference by comparing the amount of paint for painting walls in your room with amount of paint for *totally fulfilling your room* with it (from the floor to the ceiling).

Comment: Metals can be charged only on their surfaces too (Gauss's law); I thought you were saying that the effect is weaker because the charge produced by friction is not localised as in insulators but spreads over all the surface (so it is diluted); I can not understand why you are mentioning  the volume. Anyway thank you for your time

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple model without involving atomic and electronic theory. First, what is the friction process without lubrication? This is the removal from the surface of particles of material (chills, sawdust). Secondly, upon separation of a particle, an electric charge can form on it, and also the particle can be magnetized (this is an empirical fact). When a charged particle of material is separated from the insulator, a charge of the opposite sign is formed on the insulator. When a charged metal particle separates from the metal surface, an electric current arises between the particle and the surface. Therefore, an excess charge does not occur due to the high electrical conductivity of the metal.

Comment: But the air rubbing the surface of a car charges it by friction (this is the reason of the  electric shock getting out of a car), so why is it so diffult in the case of small objects such as forks?

Comment: The car body is painted, part of the body is plastic. The car is isolated from the ground by tires. This is a capacitor that can accumulate charge.

Comment: So you are saying that it is the painting that is charged by friction and not the metal of the surface of the car; is it right? (Plastic is inside the car, not on the surface, right?) Anyway thank you for your time

Comment: No, it was only an analogy.